# Hard-coded iOS keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am starting to write code for a keyboard in iOS. It's pretty much hard-coded and I need suggestions on how I can make it more professional style and more efficient.

```
 //row 1
UIButton *row1Btn1=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow1View viewWithTag:11];
UIButton *row1Btn2=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow1View viewWithTag:12];
UIButton *row1Btn3=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow1View viewWithTag:13];
UIButton *row1Btn4=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow1View viewWithTag:14];
UIButton *row1Btn5=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow1View viewWithTag:15];
UIButton *row1Btn6=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow1View viewWithTag:16];
UIButton *row1Btn7=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow1View viewWithTag:17];
UIButton *row1Btn8=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow1View viewWithTag:18];
UIButton *row1Btn9=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow1View viewWithTag:19];
UIButton *row1Btn10=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow1View viewWithTag:20];
UIButton *row1Btn11=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow1View viewWithTag:21];
UIButton *row1Btn12=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow1View viewWithTag:22];



[row1Btn1 setTitle:items[0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row1Btn2 setTitle:items[1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row1Btn3 setTitle:items[2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row1Btn4 setTitle:items[3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row1Btn5 setTitle:items[4] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row1Btn6 setTitle:items[5] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row1Btn7 setTitle:items[6] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row1Btn8 setTitle:items[7] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row1Btn9 setTitle:items[8] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row1Btn10 setTitle:items[9] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row1Btn11 setTitle:items[10] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row1Btn12 setTitle:items[11] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


//row 2

UIButton *row2Btn1=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow2View viewWithTag:23];
UIButton *row2Btn2=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow2View viewWithTag:24];
UIButton *row2Btn3=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow2View viewWithTag:25];
UIButton *row2Btn4=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow2View viewWithTag:26];
UIButton *row2Btn5=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow2View viewWithTag:27];
UIButton *row2Btn6=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow2View viewWithTag:28];
UIButton *row2Btn7=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow2View viewWithTag:29];
UIButton *row2Btn8=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow2View viewWithTag:30];
UIButton *row2Btn9=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow2View viewWithTag:31];
UIButton *row2Btn10=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow2View viewWithTag:32];
UIButton *row2Btn11=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow2View viewWithTag:33];
UIButton *row2Btn12=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow2View viewWithTag:34];

[row2Btn1 setTitle:items[12] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row2Btn2 setTitle:items[13] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row2Btn3 setTitle:items[14] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row2Btn4 setTitle:items[15] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row2Btn5 setTitle:items[16] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row2Btn6 setTitle:items[17] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row2Btn7 setTitle:items[18] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row2Btn8 setTitle:items[19] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row2Btn9 setTitle:items[20] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row2Btn10 setTitle:items[21] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row2Btn11 setTitle:items[22] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row2Btn12 setTitle:items[23] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


//row 3

UIButton *row3Btn1=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow3View viewWithTag:35];
UIButton *row3Btn2=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow3View viewWithTag:36];
UIButton *row3Btn3=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow3View viewWithTag:37];
UIButton *row3Btn4=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow3View viewWithTag:38];
UIButton *row3Btn5=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow3View viewWithTag:39];
UIButton *row3Btn6=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow3View viewWithTag:40];
UIButton *row3Btn7=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow3View viewWithTag:41];
UIButton *row3Btn8=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow3View viewWithTag:42];
UIButton *row3Btn9=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow3View viewWithTag:43];
UIButton *row3Btn10=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow3View viewWithTag:44];
UIButton *row3Btn11=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow3View viewWithTag:45];
UIButton *row3Btn12=(UIButton *)[_lettersRow3View viewWithTag:46];

[row3Btn1 setTitle:items[24] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row3Btn2 setTitle:items[25] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row3Btn3 setTitle:items[26] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row3Btn4 setTitle:items[27] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row3Btn5 setTitle:items[28] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row3Btn6 setTitle:items[29] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row3Btn7 setTitle:items[30] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row3Btn8 setTitle:items[31] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row3Btn9 setTitle:items[32] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row3Btn10 setTitle:items[33] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row3Btn11 setTitle:items[34] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row3Btn12 setTitle:items[35] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//row 4

UIButton *row4Btn1=(UIButton *)[_numbersRow1View viewWithTag:47];
UIButton *row4Btn2=(UIButton *)[_numbersRow1View viewWithTag:48];
UIButton *row4Btn3=(UIButton *)[_numbersRow1View viewWithTag:49];
UIButton *row4Btn4=(UIButton *)[_numbersRow1View viewWithTag:50];
UIButton *row4Btn5=(UIButton *)[_numbersRow1View viewWithTag:51];
UIButton *row4Btn6=(UIButton *)[_numbersRow1View viewWithTag:52];
UIButton *row4Btn7=(UIButton *)[_numbersRow1View viewWithTag:53];
UIButton *row4Btn8=(UIButton *)[_numbersRow1View viewWithTag:54];
UIButton *row4Btn9=(UIButton *)[_numbersRow1View viewWithTag:55];
UIButton *row4Btn10=(UIButton *)[_numbersRow1View viewWithTag:56];


[row4Btn1 setTitle:items[36] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row4Btn2 setTitle:items[37] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row4Btn3 setTitle:items[38] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row4Btn4 setTitle:items[39] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row4Btn5 setTitle:items[40] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row4Btn6 setTitle:items[41] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row4Btn7 setTitle:items[42] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row4Btn8 setTitle:items[43] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row4Btn9 setTitle:items[44] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[row4Btn10 setTitle:items[45] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: What is `items`?  Where is that defined?  And is `_numbersRow1View` created in IB?  (i.e, is that assigned through an `IBOutlet`?)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using the `UICollectionView` class will resolve your issue?

1. Create `UIViewController`
2. Add `UICollectionView` on storyboard
3. Add `@property (nonatomic, weak) @IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView`
4. Set delegate and datasource for `UICollectionView`:

   ```
   collectionView.delegate = self
   collectionView.dataSource = self
   ```

   Don't forget to add conformation of `UICollectionViewDelegate/ UICollectionViewDataSource` to controller.
5. Add `@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger buttonsCount;`
6. Implement dataSource methods:

   ```
   - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
       return buttonsCount;
   }
   ```
7. Create a custom `UICollectionViewCell` and implement this method:

   ```
   - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       ...
       cell.text = indexPath.row
       return cell
   }
   ```

For more detailed information, please read this [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview).